# how do u read all doubles from txt file?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

Its easy when  have a file of all doubles, but when 
there is a non-double somewhere in between,
i wouldnt be able to catch all of them.

**For example:**

```
604.2
609.2
6042
604.4
4234.324
312
gfsdgfreg
6043
604.3
```

**The output:**

```
604.2
609.2
6042.0
604.4
4234.324
312.0
```

Apparently, two doubles are missing. Is there a way
to catch all of them just by using hasNextDouble()?
Thx in advance if u dont get a reply. I saw somewhere
that I could parse each of them to double and catch the
exception, but i am really not that advanced

what i have here is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab11{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   throws FileNotFoundException{

      File nums = new File("file.txt");
      int size = arrSize(nums);

      double[] phoneNums = copy(nums,size);
      for(int i=0;i<phoneNums.length;i++)
         System.out.println(phoneNums[i]);
    }

    public static int arrSize(File f)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
       int arrSize = 0;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
       while(in.hasNextDouble()){
          arrSize++;
          in.next();
       }
       in.close();
       return arrSize;
    }

    public static double[] copy(File f,int size)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
       Scanner in =  new Scanner(f);
       double[] list = new double[size];
       int i = 0;
       while(in.hasNextDouble()){
          list[i++] = in.nextDouble();
       }
       in.close();
       return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using

```
while(in.hasNextDouble()){
    arrSize++;
    in.next();
}
```

As soon as it reaches a non-double, it will stop, and won't proceed further.
You have to keep looping through every line in the `while` loop, and within this loop, use an `if` statement to check whether what you're reading is a double or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would give your two while loops the following structure:

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
  if(in.hasNextDouble()) {
     // your inner while loop code here
  } else {
     in.next();
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll miss everything after the first instance of a non-double.

Comment: Else in.next(); or it will loop forever.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you're absolutely right. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Takendarkk said, once a non-double is found in the input in.hasNextDouble() will evaluate to false, ending your loop.

Here is an example of a (hopefully) more simplified way of doing what you are doing:

```
    // create a new list for our doubles
    List<Double> doubles = new LinkedList<>();
    try {

        // open our doubles file reader
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("doubles.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());

        // read our doubles file
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches("^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?$")) {
                doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
            }
        }

        // close our doubles file reader
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // for the sake of the example
    }

    // output our doubles
    for (Double d : doubles) {
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain the formatting symbols you are using for `line.matches`?